# How to support WebAuthN in MacOS WKWebView?

Tags: macos, wkwebview, webauthn

Safari 13 supports WebAuthN, but WKWebView doesn't. Here is the test page: https://demo.yubico.com/webauthn-technical/registration. It appears `navigator.credentials` is not implemented in WKWebView. Is there a way to add WebAuthN support?

Answer (score 3):

The correct API to use is this scenario `ASWebAuthenticationSession`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession

On iOS 13.3 that will work with USB, Lightning or NFC security keys based on our testing.

On iOS 11 or below you should use `SFAuthenticationSession` but obviously there's no WebAuthn support.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try. I forgot to mention I was looking for a solution for MacOS. Just updated the question.

Comment: Although I was talking about iOS that API is available in OSX so it's worth a go and is the recommended way to do this from Apple's PoV.